# UDP receive waits indefinitely in x64 bit mode?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

My code consist of udp server which receive data from an udp client. The code can run in two configurations win32 and x64 in visual studio. If i run the udp server in x32 mode, everything works fine, it receives data. But in x64 bit the receive wait indefinitely. No change in code, single receive command but both behave differently. My udp receive looks like this.

```
WSADATA wsadata;
int error = WSAStartup(0X0202, &wsadata);

if(error) {
    cerr<<"UdpIPV4Server.cpp:- WSAStartup failed"<<endl;
    return -1;
}
if ((socket_var = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == -1) {
    cerr<<"UdpIPV4Server.cpp:- socket function failed"<<endl;
    return -1;
}
memset((char *) &si_server, 0, sizeof(si_server));
si_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_server.sin_port = htons(7888);
char host[NI_MAXHOST] = "10.8.0.2";
if(inet_pton(AF_INET, host, &si_server.sin_addr) != 1) {
    cerr<<"UdpIPV4Server.cpp: inet_pton() failed\n";
    return -1;
}
if(bind(socket_var,(struct sockaddr *)&si_server,sizeof(si_server)) == -1) {
        cerr<<"UdpIPV4Server.cpp:- bind failed: "<<endl;
        return -1;
}
char recv_buffer[65534];
int buf_size = 65534;
memset((char*)&si_client, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
int si_client_len = sizeof(si_client);
if((recv_len = recvfrom(socket_var, recv_buffer, buf_size, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&si_client, &si_client_len)) == -1) {
        cerr<<"udpipv4server.cpp:- recvfrom failed"<<endl;
        return recv_len;
}
```

So What could be the issue, why this change in behaviour?

Comment: You should use the proper types, like `socklen_t` for `si_client_len` - if that's 64 bit on your system and you pass an `int*`, god knows what rot it will receive.  Go read your [API](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom).

Comment: @Tony Sorry for not mentioning compiler earlier. I am compiling using MSVC++. As per as [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120(v=vs.85).aspx), int* is mentioned for si_client_len.